# Optimize with another variable

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, numerical-methods, minimize

sorry i am a real beginner in Python and I really need help to understand this:
So basically I have a function who takes 4 arguments:

```
def expected_utility(p,y,x,q):
    return p*u(y-x+q-premium(p,q), theta)+(1-p)*u(y-premium(p,q))
```

(premium and u are function already defined)
I already have the value of p(=0.2) and y(=1) and I need to find the optimal q's* for several x between 0.01 and 0.9.

This is my entire code I have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def premium(p,q):
    return p*q     
def u(z,theta):
    return (z**(1+theta))/(1+theta)    
def expected_utility(p,y,x,q):
    return p*u(y-x+q-premium(p,q), theta)+(1-p)*u(y-premium(p,q))

theta=-2
y=1
p=0.2
N=100

x_array=np.linspace(0.01,0.9,N)
qs_optimal=np.empty(N)
```

And now I should create a loop for all x's in the x_array and use scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar to find all the optimals q's and store them in the qs_optimal array. How can I proceed? Thank you very very much for your help.

Comment: I underrstand your need to loop through x's and find optimal q's, but... what does that have to do with your `expected_utility()` function? That is a function that requires that you already know a `q` value as it's both an input parameter/argument AND is used in the calculation to give a return. It's not clear.

Comment: But maybe my mistake is here. Like if I have to find q* for a given x, should I remove q from the parameters?

Comment: Because I have the value of all the parameters it would be like a simple function e.g 2q+x and I should find all the optimal q's for an array of x's. Sorry if it's not clear, it's very hard for me to understand so even worse to explain...

Comment: If you don't know the value of q you can't pass it to the function. A python function (like any code) isn't like a mathematical one. You would have to solve that nasty thing for `q` so it's `q=<nasty thing>` and pass in the variables needed inside of `<nasty thing>` so it can calculate and spit out `q` and return `q` from the function. (if that helps).